# My tax calculating function is not combining numbers as a sum

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JS and trying to create a simple tax calculation formula that calculates and combines two different tax rates. Where I'm from, we have a sales tax (5.3%) and a Meals Tax (7.5%). If I plug in a test number, say $100, I get 100.1280, Which is $100 + 100*0.053 + 100*0.075.

Here's my code below:

```js
function billCalculate() {
  const billAmount = document.getElementById("saleAmount").value;
  let salesTax = (billAmount * 0.053);  
  let mealsTax = (billAmount * 0.075);
  let total = billAmount + (salesTax + mealsTax);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `Your total is $` + total + `.`;
}
```

Any hints on where I'm making this rookie mistake?

Comment: You have to convert `billAmount` to a number because field values are always strings. Just put a `+` before `document` in the `getElementById()` call.

Comment: A string value used in multiplication will be coerced into a number.  `"123" * 0.053` produces  `6.519`.  It would fail if OP enters a dollar sign though.

Comment: If I hard code `100` as the amount I get `$112.8` with your code. However if I use a string like `'100'` I get `$10012.8`, so odds are you didn't convert your input to a number. Post a [mcve] please

Comment: check variable types using `typeof <var>` and make sure you are adding/multiplying numbers and not strings

Comment: Ah, the issue is on the second to last line, where `billAmount` (a string) is added to numbers.  Which ends up coercing the numbers into strings and concatenating them.

Comment: @Pointy thank you. Can you explain what the '+' does in front of the document? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Sackadelic `+` before a string value coerces that value to a number.  As in:  `+"123"`, this is interpreted as `0+"123"`, which forces the string into a number, so it becomes `0+123`, which gives you the numeric value of `123`

Comment: Thank you, @Amy!

Comment: @Sackadelic Welcome.  For the sake of completeness, note that that behavior changes if you add a string to ___, (which is what your code does on the second to last line).  `"123"+456` tries to coerce 456 to a string, so you end up with `"123456"`.  The expression `A + B` changes its behavior depending on the data types of A and B.  I suggest you google "wat js" and watch the video by DestroyAllSoftware.  It's fun, I promise.

Comment: @Amy The video gave me a good laugh. Thanks for sharing! Any hints on preventing or ignoring the '$' to be entered?

Comment: @Sackadelic Hint: replace.